# Mailing from Flash (using Actionscript 3.0)

Tags: php, actionscript-3, email, flash-cs5

I've a flash project, the facility to be added is, send email from flash (.swf/.exe) **without redirecting**. Only sender's email id is provided and on click, form should send an email.
I googled a lot for this, php solutions were given, I could not work on it may be because of low guidance level.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pure ActionScript [SMTP mailer](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=27), such as:

http://www.bytearray.org/wp-content/projects/smtpmailer/SMTPMailer%200.6.zip

Library and FLA example included within the ZIP.

Example implementation:

[image: mailer]

```
import org.smtp.mailer.SMTPMailer;
import org.smtp.encoding.JPEGEncoder;
import org.smtp.encoding.PNGEnc;
import org.smtp.events.SMTPEvent;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.events.*;

// create the socket connection to any SMTP socket
// use your ISP SMTP

var myMailer:SMTPMailer = new SMTPMailer (smtp_txt.text, 25);

// register events
// event dispatched when mail is successfully sent
myMailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.MAIL_SENT, onMailSent);
// event dispatched when mail could not be sent
myMailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.MAIL_ERROR, onMailError);
// event dispatched when SMTPMailer successfully connected to the SMTP server
myMailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.CONNECTED, onConnected);
// event dispatched when SMTP server disconnected the client for different reasons
myMailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.DISCONNECTED, onDisconnected);
// event dispatched when the client has authenticated successfully
myMailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.AUTHENTICATED, onAuthSuccess);
// event dispatched when the client could not authenticate
myMailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.BAD_SEQUENCE, onAuthFailed);

// take the snapshot
var myBitmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData ( stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight );

// encode as JPEG with quality 100
var myEncoder = new JPEGEncoder( 100 );

send_btn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

message_txt.text = "<img src='http://www.google.com/images/logo_sm.gif'</img><br><b>Picture file attached!</b>";

function onClick ( pEvt:MouseEvent )
{
    // replace this by any DisplayObject
    myBitmap.draw ( this );

    var myCapStream:ByteArray = myEncoder.encode ( myBitmap );

    // sends HTML email
    //myMailer.sendHTMLMail ( from_txt.text, to_txt.text, subject_txt.text, "<img src='http://www.google.com/images/logo_sm.gif'</img><br><b>Picture from HTML :)</b>");

    // send HTML email with picture file attached
    myMailer.sendAttachedMail ( from_txt.text, to_txt.text, subject_txt.text, message_txt.text, myCapStream, "image.jpg");
}

function onAuthFailed ( pEvt:SMTPEvent ):void
{
    status_txt.htmlText = "Authentication Error";
}

function onAuthSuccess ( pEvt:SMTPEvent ):void
{
    status_txt.htmlText = "Authentication OK !";
}

function onConnected ( pEvt:SMTPEvent ):void 
{
    status_txt.htmlText = "Connected : \n\n" + pEvt.result.message;
    status_txt.htmlText += "Code : \n\n" + pEvt.result.code;
}

function onMailSent ( pEvt:SMTPEvent ) 
{
    // when data available, read it
    status_txt.htmlText = "Mail sent :\n\n" + pEvt.result.message;
    status_txt.htmlText += "Code : \n\n" + pEvt.result.code;
}

function onMailError ( pEvt:SMTPEvent ):void 
{
    status_txt.htmlText = "Error :\n\n" + pEvt.result.message;
    status_txt.htmlText += "Code : \n\n" + pEvt.result.code;
}

function onDisconnected ( pEvt:SMTPEvent ):void 
{
    status_txt.htmlText = "User disconnected :\n\n" + pEvt.result.message;
    status_txt.htmlText += "Code : \n\n" + pEvt.result.code;
}

function socketErrorHandler ( pEvt:IOErrorEvent ) 
{
    // when data available, read it
    status_txt.htmlText = "Connection error !";
}
```

Comment: Neat. Of course, this requires access to a fairly open SMTP server. Doesn't most (isp) SMTP servers limit usage based on IP or require authentication in some other way (and authentication information like username/password is not something you would want to put in a flash file)?

Comment: Good points.  There are some free options for SMTP servers, but I don't know terms / legalities.  I think Rackspace offers SMTP for $3 a month.  This classes supports SSL, but I'm not sure as to what encryption strengths.